# Eclipse does not autocomplete both html and php tags in php file

Tags: php, html, eclipse, autocomplete, web-development

I am using eclipse indigo. and i have installed WTP plugin.

After i open php file in webcontent/ directory of my project it does not auto complete any php synatx and html tags too..

But html file can able to auto complete html syntax..(Not php obviously).

I need the php file to auto complete the php and html syntax..

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the PDT (PHP Developer Tools) from "Install New Software".

Comment: I have downloaded PDT but did not installed the other files attached with PDT (Thought not necessary.) Now working fine